# Kendo Datepicker editor with particular Date formated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to use the Kendo Datepicker editor which is in particular format of "dd-MMM-yyyy",
that I am getting now with the code of Datepicker as::

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                      .Name("FromDate")
                      .Format("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                    )
```

But I want something like this as shown in Image below::
[image]

as shown into the image above:

1) By default the Datepicker is showing the Format

2) User just have to enter value for `dd` and the cursor automatically moves to `mmm` and when `mmm` completes then it automatically goes to `yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Kendo's newest release scheduled for this week has a new Masked Input control.  You could try combining the two controls together that way.  It might look something like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("FromDate")
    .Format("dd-MMM-yyyy")
)
```

Then have javascript to wire up the masked input.  This syntax is not exact, but I think it should get you on the right path.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Only want the masked input on the input of the control
      $("#FromDate input").kendoMaskedTextBox({
          mask: "**-***-****"
      });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

As an alternative, you can use the Digital Bush Masked Input plugin found here: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ which might look something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Only want the masked input on the input of the control
      $("#FromDate input").mask('**-***-****');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Kendo UI has not Provided Masked textBox for MVC applications.

Comment: The release is scheduled for this week as I said in my first sentence.  I suspect tomorrow, or Thursday at the latest.

Comment: What if I want to implement it in Previous release. 
Because at this stage I cant replace the Kendo version because it will raise more issues

Comment: I've used this plugin before: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/  Not sure how it plays with a Kendo UI component though.

Comment: Can you just help me to do in this Link http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/x4dA9/266/

it should be in format like "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: Thanks for this, But there isn't any kin dof validation for Datetime as '99-999-9999'   which is not good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49992/discussion-between-rahul-rj-and-mmillican)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use mask jquery in kendo scheduler.Here is my example to display date format in kendo scheduler.First you have download Mask input plugin and you can do like this................

```
    <div class="row form-group">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
         <label for="fname">Start Date (MM/DD/YYYY)</label>
            <input kendo-date-picker k-format="'MM/dd/yyyy'" ng-model="_OrgTicker.StartDate" style="width:100%;" id="dateFormat" />
       </div>
   </div>
```

This is your script given below

```
                <script>
                    $(function () {
                        var dateFormat = $("#dateFormat");
                        dateFormat.kendoMaskedTextBox({
                            mask: "00/00/0000"
                        });
                        //dateFormat.kendoDatePicker();
                        //dateFormat.closest(".k-datepicker").add(dateFormat).removeClass("k-textbox");
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a custom date picker which validates the entered date string against a date regex.  You can use this as a stand alone datepicker or part of a form where you have unobtrusive validation enabled.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString KendoDatePicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string value, int width, string className = "", bool required = false, string formId = "")
    {
        var cssClassName = "";
        cssClassName = required ? String.Format("{0} {1}", className, "required") : className;

        //MM/dd/yyyy, M/dd/yyyy, MM-dd-yyyy, M-dd-yyyy
        var regex = @"^([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2])[- / .]([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[- / .](1[9][0-9][0-9]|2[0][0-9][0-9])$";

        if (required)
        {
            string elementValidationScript = "";
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(formId))
            {
                elementValidationScript = "$('#" + formId + "').validate().element('#" + name + "');";
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
             "$(function() {" +
                                      "$.validator.messages.required = '*';" + //If were using unobtrusive validation, this changes the default required validator message to simply an asterisk
                                      "$('#" + name + "').kendoDatePicker();" + //create the date picker
                                       @"function isMMDDYYYYFormat(str, dateControl) { var isMatch = str.match(/" + regex + "/); if(!isMatch) { dateControl.addClass('input-validation-error'); dateControl.val(''); alert('Please enter a valid date value in the following format MM/dd/YYYY') } else { dateControl.removeClass('input-validation-error'); } };" +
                                      "$('#" + name + "').blur(function(e){ isMMDDYYYYFormat($(this).val(), $(this)); " + elementValidationScript + " }); " +
                          "})" +
                          "" +
             "</script>" +
         "<input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\" class='datePicker " + cssClassName + "'" + " style=\"width:" + width + "px;\" />");
        }
        else
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
           "$(function() {" +
                                    "$('#" + name + "').kendoDatePicker();" +
                                     @"function isMMDDYYYYFormat(str, dateControl) { var isMatch = str.match(/" + regex + "/); if(!isMatch) { dateControl.addClass('input-validation-error'); dateControl.val(''); alert('Please enter a valid date value in the following format MM/dd/YYYY') } else { dateControl.removeClass('input-validation-error'); } };" +
                                    "$('#" + name + "').blur(function(e){ $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error'); if($(this).val() != null && $(this).val().length > 0) { isMMDDYYYYFormat($(this).val(), $(this)); }}); " +
                                    "$('#" + name + "').removeAttr('data-val-date');" + //removes the default date validation message 
                        "})" +
           "</script>" +
       "<input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" value=\"" + value + "\" id=\"" + name + "\" name=\"" + name + "\" class='datePicker " + cssClassName + "'" + " style=\"width:" + width + "px;\" />");

        }
```